# What does mean "unparalleled run" in context of publication of books

Tags: phrase-usage

What does mean "unparalleled run" in context of publication of books?

Context:

> Unknown Dimension is what you might call a Specialist publishing house-- we traffic in the weird, the ahead-of-its-time, the lost-but-not-forgotten-by-a-small-but-dedicated-group-of-plugged-in-bibliophiles type of out-there mass-market-shunning visionary expression that refuses to be taken on anything but its own terms. We've *had an unparalleled run* since our inception four years ago, unearthing and reviving, Christ- (or Zombie-)like, timeless works such as N.N. Bestman's Message of the Snakemen, IT'S INSIDE ME! by Jens Keller, and Emil Krieger's oft-banned Venusian Fleshtraders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, an *unparalleled run* is a string of events, efforts, or results that nobody else is able to match.  The term is generally used to highlight someone's (or something's) success in a chosen field.

The idea behind the expression is that if you arrange your results along a timeline, then in order for someone else to have a line that is parallel to yours, they would have to have just as many good results in just as short of a time period as you did; but your results were so exceptional that there is nobody else that was able to achieve so much, so quickly, and therefore everyone else's graph will diverge from yours.

Comment: Yes. See the Oxford Advanced Learners Dictionary under [Run (noun), definition 3](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/run_2).

Comment: Just to clarify: While the example given is about publishing, the phrase "unparalleled run" has nothing to do with publishing. You could talk about an unparalleled run in coal mining or ping pong or anything.